# problemas con axios.get parametros http

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-axios

tengo un inconvente cuando utilizo la ruta sin parametros todo funciona bien **pero cuando envio la ruta con parametros no carga nada la paginacion** pero el console.log funciona y en inspeccionar elementos aparece un error "Invalid prop `data` supplied to `MaterialTable`."  he intentado de muchas formas pero no he podido solucionar.

```js
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react';
 
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import axios from 'axios';
 
 
function Paginacion() {
  
 
  const [data, setData]=useState([]);
 
  //la ruta http funciona sin problemas por que no lleva parametros
  /*
  const peticionGet =async() =>{
    await axios.get('https://www.creditos.hoztcreative.com/apiCreditos/paginacion/')
    .then(response=>{
    setData(response.data);
     console.log(response.data);
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
 
  }*/
 
 
 
  
  // la ruta http no funciona con parametros
  const peticionGet =async() =>{
    await axios.get('https://www.creditos.hoztcreative.com/apiCreditos/paginacion/index.php?documento=1110498191')
    .then(response=>{
    setData(response.data);
     console.log(response.data);
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
}
 
 
  useEffect(()=>{
    peticionGet();
 
  },[])
 
    
  const columnas =[
    {
      title:"RUTA",
      field: "id_ubicacion"
    },
    {
      title:'NOMBRE',
      field:'pais'
    },
    {
      title:"APELLIDO",
      field: "departamento"
    },
    
    
  ];
 
    return (
 
        <div className="content-wrapper">
    
   
<MaterialTable
     
columns={columnas}
data={data}
pagination
fixedHeader
 
 
options={{
  actionsColumnIndex: -1
}}
options={{
 actionsCellStyle: {
 },
 
}}
localization={{
    header:{
    actions: 'ACCIONES'
    
  },
 
   
}}
 
/>
 
 
    
  </div>
    );
}
 
export default Paginacion
```

Comment: Hola, la url esta devolviendo un array de objetos cuando no le pasas parametros. Y si le pasas parametros te devuelve el objeto directamente. ¿Has contemplado esa situación?

Comment: hola amigo, si, cuando la url  esta sin parametros este se muestra en el setData sin problemas pero apenas le agrego parametros a la url no carga pero si saco un console.log me muestra el array o si pruebo en postman.

Comment: Cuando le pasas parametros a la url, que te muestra en el console.log? UN objeto o un Array?

Comment: ya puede solucionar , solo era cambiar data={data} por data={[data]} para que funcionara la url con parametros.

Answer (score 1):

Primero valida **si se trata de un array u objeto**. Si no es un array lo reasignas para que se vuelva **array** y luego llamas a **setData**.

```
let data = response.data;
if (!Array.isArray(data)){
  data = [data];
}

setData(data);
```

Comment: de acuerdo con el codigo que subi como quedaria ? , he intentado de muchas formas pero no he podido.